# Connection of python 3.10.9 with Matrikon Server

Tags: python, opc

I am currently working on connecting Python with Matrikon Server Simulation. I am encountering several issues and am not aware of its default port. Nevertheless, I am facing errors in the process.

Python Code:

```
import opcua
c = opcua.Client("opc.tcp://localhost:53530/Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1")
c.connect()
```

Errors:

```
Discovery Error: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

My Matrikon server:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple OPC specifications, and they use different communication protocols. The OPC client library you are using must support the OPC specification provided by the OPC server.

MatrikonOPC Simulation server supports OPC-DA (COM/DCOM based), but you are apparently using some OPC client library for OPC-UA (Unified Architecture), so that is not ever going to work directly.

In order to connect to MatrikonOPC Simulation server from Python, use some library that supports OPC-DA, such as:

- QuickOPC: https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/python
- OpenOPC

Comment: I have tried all of them no one is working, please can u guide me in it as well?

Comment: I suggest you follow the usual stackoverflow procedure - roughly: describe what you have done, what results you expected, and what results you actually got.

Comment: My task is just to make the python connection with Matrikon Simulation Server and read some tags. just. I have wrtten this code: "import OpenOPC
import time
    opc = OpenOPC.client()
    opc.servers() # list available OPC servers
    opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1', 'localhost') " but it still showing the error: name 'pythoncom' is not defined. i have done all the solution for it as well

Comment: I have follow this video and its working now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbubVMlPP6Y